# How to achieve responsive design in a Phaser game in a way where the whole screen is the camera/viewport and the focus change on resize?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I want to achieve this kind of responsiveness:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Note that as you resize, the camera/viewport uses the whole screen and what changes is the focused area - the UI elements (represented here by the score) also are adjusted following the viewport size.
How can I achieve this kind of design using Phaser 3?

I'd like to distribute my game for different sizes of screens, mobile, tablets and desktops.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a topic that is a bit difficult, but basically you could use the property-vale `Phaser.Scale.FIT` of the scalemanager ([check out this documentation](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/scalemanager/)) and [these official examples](https://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=scalemanager/&q=).

Something like this should work:

```
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    scale: {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
        autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
        width: 800,   // <-- Size of the game
        height: 600   // <-- Size of the game
    },
    ...
};
```